# Notepad++ - How to find a line that does not start with a character string and merge it to the previous line?

Tags: notepad++

I want to search all the lines that does not start with 'OPM' and then merge those lines to the previous line

I have this text:

```
OPM1352 - a
b 
c 
OPM9574 - d 
OPM5841 - e
```

And I want the output:

```
OPM1352 - abc 
OPM9574 - d 
OPM5841 - e
```

Comment: I suppose you would need to use some regular expressions. [These docs](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions) should be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ctrl`+`H` (alt. Search -> Replace...), then select `regular expressions`. Enable `Wrap around`. Then `Find what`:

```
[\r\n](?!OPM)
```

`Replace with`: empty

And replace all.

Comment: That's great! Thank you @Renat